# dlopen with two shared libraries, exporting symbols

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have a linux shared library, foo.so, which is loaded from an executable using `dlopen("foo.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL)`. From foo.so I'd like to dlopen another library, bar.so, which references symbols defined in foo.so, but the linker fails to find them. I can't change RTLD_LOCAL to RTLD_GLOBAL, because I don't have the source to the executable doing the loading. I thought `-Wl,--export-dynamic` when linking foo.so might help but it doesn't override the local flag to dlopen. GCC's new attribute visibility feature doesn't look like it offers the answer either.

Is there a way I can instruct the linker to resolve references to undefined symbols in bar.so to those definitions in foo.so, without linking bar with -lfoo or similarity moving the symbols into a 3rd library and linking both foo and bar against it?  The only thing that occurs to me is to dlopen foo.so with RTLD_GLOBAL from within foo.so itself, then dlopen bar.so, but that strikes me as a bit of a mess. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Link `foo.so` against `bar.so`.

When the executable `dlopen()`s `foo.so`, `bar.so` will also be loaded.

Alternatively, binary-patch the executable to add `RTLD_GLOBAL` to the flags for `dlopen()` call. The code will look something like

```
    movl    $2, 4(%esp)       # $2 == RTLD_NOW; RTLD_LOCAL is 0
    movl    $0xNNNNN, (%esp)  # $0xNNNNN == &"foo.so"
    call    dlopen
```

Patch it to `movl $0x102, 4(%esp)` instead (`RTLD_GLOBAL == 0x100`), and voilà.

EDIT:
If you know the name of `bar.so`, then you can link `foo.so` against a "stub" `bar.so`. It doesn't matter that you don't have "real" `bar.so`; all that matters is that `foo.so` has a dependency on it. At runtime that dependency will cause `bar.so` to be loaded whenever `foo.so` is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't link foo.so against bar.so because bar.so will be a user-provided plug-in. I also can't patch the executable because that'll typically be root-owned on the customer's system and I'm not sure patching it would go down too well with them, it does complicate the install process quite a bit. It would also break other libraries that the exec is opening, some of them rely on RTLD_LOCAL. I think I'll have to go with the dlopen foo.so from itself hack, that seems to work. Cheers

Comment: Came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56373416/linux-shared-library-depends-on-symbols-in-another-shared-library-opened-by-dlop), what if the `bar.so` does not exist when `foo.so` is loaded, but it will be there while the host program running, and loaded by `dlopen`? Is there any way to achieve this and avoid the `undefined symbol` problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a another way show as following:

excutable --dlopen local--> fakefoo.so(rename to foo) --dlopen global--> foo.so(rename to other)