# Linux shared library depends on symbols in another shared library opened by dlopen with RTLD_LOCAL

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have a shared library `libmain.so`, loaded by the host program with `dlopen("libmain.so", RTLD_LOCAL)`, and under some conditions, `libmain.so` will load another shared library, `libpatch.so`, also with `dlopen`. The problem is, **libpatch.so depends on symbols inside libmain.so**, so how can I solve this?

1. Change `RTLD_LOCAL` to `RTLD_GLOBAL` is not an option due to permission reasons.
2. [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358902/dlopen-with-two-shared-libraries-exporting-symbols) is a question quite similar to this one, the solution to that problem is to make `libpatch.so` a dependency of `libmain.so`, so it will be loaded when `libmain.so` is loaded, but my `libpatch.so` should be loaded conditionally, `libpatch.so` might not be there when `libmain.so` is linked.

EDIT: the original problem I want to solve is:

When the process is running, we may find that there is a bug in function `SomeFunction` inside `libmain.so`, **but the process cannot be restarted and `libmain.so` cannot be reloaded**, so we have to provide a `libpatch.so` with bug-fixed function `SomeFunction`, and send a signal to the process, make it to load `libpatch.so`, and use `SomeFunction` in `libpatch.so` instead the buggy one in `libmain.so`. However, `SomeFunction` depends on a global variable `GlobalVar`, and it might have changed in `libmain.so`, so we want to link `SomeFunction` to it inside `libmain.so`, but `libmain.so` is loaded with `RTLD_LOCAL`, `GlobalVar` cannot be referenced when `libpatch.so` is loading.

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD` the shared object `libpatch.so` when needed.

Comment: @jww AFAIK, `LD_PRELOAD` trick loads a `so` before the program launches, however, when my host program launches, `libpatch.so` may be not ready, and I need to load it during the host program running, without restart the host program, can `LD_PRELOAD` achieve this?

Comment: What problem are you *actually* trying to solve? See http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @EmployedRussian Sorry for the unclear description, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Compile a list of symbols from libmain.so needed by libpatch.so. Build a data structure that contains addresses of these symbols. Build libpatch.so not against libmain.so but against this data structure. Pass an instance of it to libpatch.so initialisation function.

Comment: Do you have a resource link for further information, on how to achieve this?

Comment: @AmeyaVS no, no link, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way:

1. compile libpatch.so with libmain.so
2. dlopen libmain.so again in libpatch.so

detail ref:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-0690/chapter3-14/index.html